# How to exclude NFS directories with find?

Tags: find, nfs

I need to search for files that has no user OR no group.

```
find / -nouser -o -nogroup
```

I think this is OK. But, I don't want to search NFS shares. How can I exclude the NFS shares in the find command?

Comment: Try 
`find / -fstype ext4 -nouser -o -nogroup`
Substitute ext3, etc. if you're not using ext4

Comment: please post this as answer

Comment: @DougO'Neal you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @DougO'Neal, that wouldn't stop `find` from descending into nfs FS, just not to print the files it would find there.

Comment: For using -exec with something like `du` combining `-fstype` and `-xdev` (aka `-mount`) seems necessary

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With GNU find, you can use the `-fstype` predicate:

```
find / -fstype nfs -prune -o \( -nouser -o -nogroup \) -print
```

Having said that, hymie's approach probably makes more sense: white-list what FS you want to search rather than black-listing those that you don't want to search.

If you want to only include `jfs2` file systems (assuming `/` is on `jfs2`), then, you need to write it:

```
find / ! -fstype jfs2 -prune -o \( -nouser -o -nogroup \) -print
```

Don't write it:

```
find / -fstype jfs2 \( -nouser -o -nogroup \) -print
```

As while that would stop `find` from printing files in non-jfs2 filesystem, that would not stop it from crawling those non-jfs2 filesystems (which you need `-prune` for).

Note that `-a` (*AND* which is implicit if omitted) has precedence over `-o` (*OR*), so you need to watch whether parenthesis are needed or not.

The above *correct* command is short for:

```
find / \( \( ! -fstype jfs2 \) -a -prune \) -o \
  \( \( -nouser -o -nogroup \) -a -print \)
```

Answer (score 12):

The closest you will probably get is to use `-xdev` , which means "Don't descend directories on other filesystems."   Then you'll need to specify which filesystems you **do** want to search.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest to to use *-not*

```
 find / -not -fstype nfs -nouser -o -nogroup
```

[Attribution](https://alvinalexander.com/linux-unix/linux-find-files-not-matching-filename-pattern-dont-match/)

Answer (score 1):

I tried specific find options for this and encountered problems, so switched to this method:

```
find $(mount | awk '!/:/ {printf "%s ", $3}') -xdev
```

This should search all file systems which are not NFS mounted.